# regex to replace the special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have the following code

```
 <span id="{{policy.pname}}_query" class="policy-tag">{{policy.policy_groups[0].query}}</span>
```

and the output of

```
 policy.policy_groups[0].query
```

is `tags:(taga || tagb || tagc)`

and I want regex to delete the first character '(' , the last ')' and replace '||' with ','

so the final output is `tags:taga,tagb,tagc`

Have tried it but no lucks. I can do this from controller but not right in the html.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

-kim

Comment: [`.replace("(", "").replace(/\)(?!.*\))/, "").replace(/\s*\|\|\s*/g, ",")`](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldvv15ep/)

Comment: or simpler, assuming there are no other () or || that needs to stay: `.replace(/[\(\)]/g,"").replace(/ \|\| /g,",")`

Comment: @Kim, do you want to remove *all* `(` and `)` in the string?

Comment: Thanks, Only the first '(' and the last ")'

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this:

```js
console.log(
  'tags:(taga || tagb || tagc)'.replace(/\(|\)/g, "").replace(/\s*\|\|\s*/g, ",")
)
```

Explanation:

```
.replace(
  / <-- open regex
  \( <-- find literal opening parenthesis
  | <-- or
  \) <-- find literal closing parenthesis
  /g <-- in the whole string
  ,  <-- "replace" method delimiter
  "" <-- replace with empty string
)
.replace( 
  / <-- open regex again
  \s* <-- find zero or more spaces
  \| <-- find a pipe
  \| <-- find another pipe
  \s* <-- find zero or more spaces after that
  /g <-- in the whole string
  , <-- "replace" method delimiter
  "," <-- replace with commas
)
```

This regex assumes that there are no parenthesis in your tags, if that is not the case, let me know and I'll update this to address that.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry . Have tried this  <span id="{{policy.pname}}_query" class="policy-tag">{{policy.policy_groups[0].query.replace(/\(|\)/g, "").replace(/\s*\|\|\s*/g, ",") }}</span> but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks - for very detail explain about this regular expression

Comment: Try: span id="{{policy.pname}}_query" class="policy-tag">{{policy.policy_groups[0].query.replace(/\(|\)/g, "").replace(/\s*\|\|\s*/g, ",") }}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use a replace filter (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-filters)

```html
<span id="{{policy.pname}}_query" class="policy-tag">{{policy.policy_groups[0].query | string.replace:"/([\(\)]| *\|{2} *)/": "," }}</span>
```

Comment: Have tried this  <span id="{{policy.pname}}_query" class="policy-tag">{{policy.policy_groups[0].query.replace(/\(|\)/g, "").replace(/\s*\|\|\s*/g, ",") }}</span> but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without regular expressions. More verbose, but easier to read and maintain.

```
var string = policy.policy_groups[0].query;
var first = string.indexOf('(');
var last = string.indexOf(')');
string = string.substring(0, first) + string.substring(first + 1, last) + string.substring(last + 1);
string.split(' || ').join(',');
```